# Running applications with DB roles defined

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a question on how we currently deploy applications on premises and how this would work in Azure.

So our on premises application is as follows:

- We have a web application deployed on
  our web server (WebAppExample1) that
  talks to an application
  (AppServerExample1) on our App
  Server.
- AppServerExample1 goes to our
  database for data in Table1.
- In our database the only application that
  requires permission to Table1 is
  AppServerExample1, so we create a DB
  Role and grant appropriate
  permissions. We associate this role
  with an Active directory user
  (AppServerExample1User) that
  AppServerExample1 runs as.

How can this be done in Azure?

From looking at some samples I dont see anyone defining permissions at this level, which to me should be done (least privelage).

Also I believe you can not be an Admin in SQL Azure so does this mean you cannot create DB roles?
Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I've read I believe you can create Roles in SQL Azure - e.g. see http://www.structuretoobig.com/post/2010/02/13/SQL-Azure-Logins.aspx

If you try and find you can't, then perhaps you could achieve this using users with different permissions rather than roles - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336235.aspx#DatabasePerms

> This database-level permission model in SQL Azure Database is same as
>   an on-premise instance of SQL Server.
>   For information, see the following
>   topics in SQL Server Books Online
>   references.
>
> Identity and Access Control (Database Engine)
>      Managing Logins, Users, and Schemas How-to Topics
>      Lesson 2: Configuring Permissions on Database Objects